# Cloudflare Pages Web Analytics breaks AMP pages

Tags: cloudflare, amp-html, web-analytics

Hope I can help avoiding surprises.
I couldn't find any documentation on this behaviour.

On Cloudflare Pages you can activate Web Analytics with the automatic setup button.

[image]

If you have AMP pages you will experience a spike in errors from the Webmaster Tools.
[image]

What happen is that Cloudflare doesn't respect the restrains about custom javascript on AMP pages.

[image]

The AMP validator output:
[image]

The page "[configuring web analytics](https://developers.cloudflare.com/analytics/web-analytics/configuring-web-analytics/rules)" declares:
[image]

Inside "Manage site" in "Advanced options"  there's no "add rule" option. You only have a checkbox with "Disable automatic setup".
[image]

What's recommended is to install the snippet manually in the pages you want to be tracked and avoid it on AMP pages.

Comment: This is definitely useful info, thanks for posting! Only suggestion would be to format it as a question (which you can then answer / accept as solution below).

Other thing would mention, I wonder if you could make use of the Web Analytics rules to disable them on AMP pages? https://developers.cloudflare.com/analytics/web-analytics/configuring-web-analytics/rules

Although honestly seems like behavior Cloudflare should be following by default. May be worth contacting them about this if you haven't yet.

Comment: I've updated the text to clarify the contradiction between the documentation and the reality. I've contacted the email Help Center and haven't received an answer in 6 days.
I will accept recommendation to have a better title, thanks for commenting David